# How to build a custom material-ui component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I have to customize the `TextField` component to build a time duration compomnent.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out the [Composition](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/) documentation. It outlines exactly how to create a customized component built on top of an existing one.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of own research on the matter. The community is here to help with your fight, not fight for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's in the spirit of SO to simply provide you with an implementation, so I'm going to try to help break this down and point you in the direction of the docs that should help you and an approach that could work for you.

This looks like you'll need to compose some lower-level MUI components together. Take a look at the [MUI TextField](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs) docs on customization and you can see an example of using `InputBase`, which you'll likely need.

Another point here is that any `TextField` component from MUI is going to provide you with a single value for change events. It looks like what you have here is a compound value.

```js
function DurationField({ value, onChange }) {
  // For example, you could model the value for this field to be an array of two values.
  const [hours, minutes] = value
  return (
    // instead of div, you may need FormControl and FormControlLabel, etc.
    <div>
      <InputBase value={hours} onChange={(e) => {
        onChange([e.target.value, minutes])
      }} />
      <InputBase value={minutes} onChange={(e) => {
        onChange([hours, e.target.value])
      }} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

You're also going to have to think about what the focus states are going to look like. How does a user use their keyboard to navigate into, through, and out of this input? What do the styles look like for those?

But from here, you should take a look at `FormControl` etc., all of the lower-level components you can find at the bottom of the `TextField` doc page I linked to. By using those, carefully overriding styles where needed, and thoughtfully crafting the value/onChange props, you should be able to make a nice component that works well within the MUI world.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you don't need to create a custom MUI component, you can use what the library provides already.

for date/time picker MUI suggests to use [material-ui-pickers library](https://next.material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/timepicker)